# `iiptables input policy drop` becomes `all forward drop`

Tags: iptables

iptablses drops all inputs.
Then `forward` that is being transferred will also be dropped.

INPUT should not affect FORWARD in my perception....

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o $2 -j MASQUERADE
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i $2 -o $1 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i $1 -o $2 -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -P INPUT DROP
```

Answer (score 0):

This solved it.

```sh
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o $2 -j MASQUERADE
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i $2 -o $1 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i $1 -o $2 -j ACCEPT

sudo iptables -t filter -A INPUT -i eth0 -j DROP
```